# Unbounded IFF A Subsequence Diverges to Infinity (from defns)

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose a sequence $(s_n)$ is unbounded. Then for any $q$ (in the metric space $(s_n)$ is) and any real $M$, there's some $s_n$ s.t. $|s_n - q| > M$. Thus, for $M_1$, there's some $s_{n_1}$ with $s_{n_1} > M_1$ and for $M_2$, there's some $s_{n_2}$ with $s_{n_2} > M_2$ and so on. Looks like we found a subsequence that diverges.

But a defn of divergence says "for any real $M$, there's some natural $N$ s.t.$n \ge N \implies s_n \ge M$. All we need is to find that $N$. Let $n = N$, then since $n_i \ge n$, we have $n_i \ge N$ and $s_{n_i} > M_i$.

If that's not the right $N$, how do we find it?

Now suppose $(s_{n_k})$ diverges to infinity. Then for any real $M$, there's some natural $N$ with $s_{n_k} > M$ whenever $n_k \ge N$ (or is it $k \ge N$?) We want to show for any real $q$ and $M, \ |s_n - q| > M$ meaning $s_{n_k} - q < -M$ and $s_{n_k} - q > M$. Since in the defn of divergence $M$ is arbitrary, any real $M, q$, there exists some $s_{n_k}$ with $s_{n_k} > M + q$. But how do we find $s_{n_k}$ with $s_{n_k} - q < - M$? Thanks.

Edit:

Definitions as they appear in my book:

[image]

[image]

Comment: For the second part see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760193/divergent-subsequence-of-an-unbounded-sequence?rq=1

Comment: This is very hard to follow.  Are you working in a general metric space or just in $\mathbb R$?  Either way, there's no universal method for determining when some sequence starts to exceed a specific threshold.  It depends on the sequence, and it can sometimes be very difficult.  And, writing e.g. $|s_n-q|>M$ does NOT mean that "$s_{n_k}-q<-M$ and $s_{n_k}-q>M$".  Indeed, those two inequalities would generally be incompatible.

Comment: @lulu, I am loosely following Rudin where he gives defns for general metric spaces whereever possible, but in this case I am working in reals. I tried using the following property: $|a | \ge b \iff  a \le -b\ \text{ or } a \ge b$. Why can't we apply it above?

Comment: There is a big difference between "or" and "and".  Also, it appears that you are only considering the case of sequences that diverge to $+\infty$.  If you want to include other sorts of divergence, the story gets more complicated.

Comment: Does that mean showing $s_{n_k} - q > M$ is enough?

Comment: I have no idea what $n, k, q, M$ are.  For clarity, you need to state exactly what assumptions you want to make about your sequence. I suggest sticking to $\mathbb R$.  You seem to pass in and out of the context of a general metric space, and that adds to the confusion.  But the real confusion lies in the fact that you never say what you are assuming about the sequence.  You start by saying just that it is unbounded.  Then you seem to assume that it diverges to $+\infty$.  Clarity is needed.

Comment: To be clear:  a sequence  or real numbers $\{s_n\}$ is "bounded" if and only if there is some constant $L$ such that $|s_n|<L$ for all $n$.  An unbounded sequence is a sequence which is not bounded.  That means that either some subsequence diverges to $+\infty$ or some subsequence diverges to $-\infty$ (or both).  It does not mean that the entire sequence diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: I added defns from my book exactly as they are into the body of my question in my OP.